# Notation for choosing the second largest number in a set

Tags: notation

Suppose we have the following set $A=\{2,4,6,8\}$. We know that if we apply a $\max$ operator on this set we will get $\max\{A\}=8$.

I'm wondering what notation would I use if i was interested not in the largest number, but rather the second largest number which in this case is $6$.

Im thinking along the line of $\max^2\{A\}=6$ or more generally an operator which chooses the $i^{th}$ largest number from this set as $\max^i\{A\}$.

Does any formal notation of this sort exist?

Comment: $\max\{A~$ \ $~C\} ~: C = \{\max(A)\}.$

Comment: $\max\{A\setminus \max\{A\}\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after getting some help off of stackexchange, I was told about [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic). This is really convenient notation as you can say "the second largest number in set $A$" is by writing $A_{(n-1)}$. In our case we have:

$$A_{(n-1)}=6$$

Comment: It is not convenient, as you have to know the number of elements of $A$ — $n$ in your examples — before you know what value of subscript $k$ to use. To name the 2nd largest member of $A$, you write $A_{(4)}$ if $A$ has $5$ elements but $A_{(99)}$ if it has $100$. A general expression for "the second largest number in $A$" would be $A_{(|A| - 1)}$, but that's a very opaque way of saying what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no statistician, but I'm not aware of an existing notation for what you're seeking. However, you can just make your own, if you give a clear definition. Something like:

> For convenience, we’ll write $\max_{(k)}(A)$ for the $k$-th largest  member of $A$. The is the dual notion to the $k$-th [*order statistic*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of $A$, usually written $A_{(k)}$, which is the $k$-th *smallest* member of $A$. They are related by $${\max}_{(k)}(A) := - ((-A)_{(k)}).$$ Thus, $\max_{(1)}$ is just $\max$.

Your new notation is defined exactly when the existing order statistic notation is defined, so you don’t really have to spell out what it means when $k = 0$ or $k \gt |A|$. A subscript on "$\max$" is preferable to a superscript, as "$\max^k$" brings to mind $\sin^k$ and $\cos^k$ where the superscript means "to the $k$-th power".

For symmetry with $A_{(k)}$, you could instead adopt the notation $A^{(k)}$. But if $A$ is a complex expression then the operator notation will be easier to read than the order-stats style notation. (If $A$ is more than just a variable, you’ll be wrapping it in parentheses in either case.) Seeing “max” first tells you up front that the entire expression, however complicated, is a number and not a set — the verb comes first, not last.